# What type of motor to use for a crank-style window opener?

Tags: motor, diy

I'm trying to build an automatic window opener for my crank-out style casement windows, but I'm a little stumped on what sort of motor to use. I need something with high torque and a good feedback mechanism so I can be sure I won't damage the window or the motor.

A servo motor was my first thought, so I can control the position exactly, but I can't find one that has the kind of travel and torque that I need. A planetary gear DC motor with an encoder might work, but they are very noisy and generally too large for my application.

- 8 full rotations of the crankshaft takes the window from closed to completely open.
- Moving the window requires about 100 oz-in of torque generally, but it will briefly require 400 oz-in in order to pull it snuggly shut when closing.
- The motor cannot be self-locking for obvious reasons.
- Needs to be somewhat compact, maybe 4 inches max in any dimension.
- Speed isn't super important but at least 30 rpm would be nice.
- Quiet operation would also be nice.

Any suggestions?

Comment: For 8 full rotations you might find it easier to measure the window position than the motor position. You could use two microswitches to detect when the window is fully open and fully closed. You could also try controlling the current through the motor - a stalled motor draws more current (this is your back-stop in case the switches fail)

Comment: Why not "self-locking"? Many car window mechanisms use a worm gear

Comment: @Ralph Because if it's self-locking, when I close the window tightly, that will cause the motor to lock and I won't be able to get it open.  It's not a car window, it's a crank-out window, with the hinge on the side.  So I have to pull it closed tightly in order get it to seal.